# using jQuery with socket.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, sockets

I am trying to use jQuery in my socket.io js (index.js) file.

Whenever I try to do

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> 
<script src="index.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io();
  $('form').submit(function(){
    socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
    $('#m').val('');
    return false;
  });
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
  });
  socket.on('new user', function(data){
    $('#newUserMessage').text(data);
  });        
</script>
```

I get this error in my console

```
GET http://localhost:3000/index.js 

ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

I'm not sure why this would happen?

But if I remove it I cant use jQuery's functions in index.js?

**My index.js file**

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

var $usernameInput = $('.usernameInput');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.broadcast.emit('new user', 'New User Joined, Say Hi :D');
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

function setUsername () {
  username = cleanInput($usernameInput.val().trim());

  if (username) {
    socket.emit('add user', username);
  }
}
```

Comment: You have provided the client code, what is the server code?

Comment: @BaldBantha I've included it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are a little confused, you have your front end and you have your back end.

Your **index.js** is your back end, you run that using NodeJS and you don't try to use jQuery on your back end, there's no DOM to manipulate. Also you don't include **index.js** on your front end, that's back end code.

This is wrong:

```
var $usernameInput = $('.usernameInput');
```

You can't access your DOM to get that value you have to send it to the back end, with some kind of event like this:

**Front end**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> 
<script>
  var socket = io();
  $('form').submit(function(){
    socket.emit('chatMessage', $('#m').val());
    $('#m').val('');
    return false;
  });
  socket.on('connect', function(){
    socket.emit('setUser', $('.usernameInput').val().trim());
  });
  socket.on('chatMessage', function(msg){
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
  });
  socket.on('newUser', function(data){
    $('#newUserMessage').text(data);
  });        
</script>
```

Back end

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.broadcast.emit('newUser', 'New User Joined, Say Hi :D');
  socket.on('setUser', function(username){
    console.log(username); //here you have your user name
  });
  socket.on('chatMessage', function(msg){
    io.emit('chatMessage', msg);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is My code for socket IO**

```
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] . '://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . ":8000" ?>');
    console.log("tests" + socket);
    socket.on('connect', function () {

    });
    socket.on('call_admin_notification', function (data) {
        getAdminNotification();
    });       

</script>
```